# How to Break the line PHP concatenate?

Tags: php

Is it possible to break the line in the following code

```
$data['snippets_html']=  $bootstrap_css.''.$bootstrap_js.''.$jquery_js.''.$ContentDecodedHTML;
```

I tried it like

```
$data['snippets_html']=  $bootstrap_css.'<br>'.$bootstrap_js.'<br>'.$jquery_js.'<br>'.$ContentDecodedHTML;
```

Comment: You mean break line after printing ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you define "break the line"? As in newline as `\r\n` or do you want it a break row for HTML? Please to give an example of the desired output.

Comment: Yes I wants to prints them on every new line

Comment: What you have tried should work. What's the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) to add line break and interpret it as such across platform ( Windows/Linux).

```
$data['snippets_html'] =  $bootstrap_css . PHP_EOL . $bootstrap_js . PHP_EOL . $jquery_js . PHP_EOL . $ContentDecodedHTML;
```

[Working Link](https://eval.in/1092129)